# When I boot computer has only a black display

Tags: 11.10, ati, hybrid-graphics

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 64x beside Windows 7.

When I start the computer, I have to choose between the operating systems, but when I choose Ubuntu, the display is black, only the cursor is visible. I am able to log in, and I can hear the sound, but the display is black. but when I start Ubuntu in recovery mode, and I choose "normal start" it works.

I have installed Ubuntu again, but I have the same problem. I know, that the driver for my ATI Radeon are not installed. When I want to update them it works, but when I restart they are gone.

Please help me

Answer (score 2):

I have already found the problem. i switched "switchable" to "descrete" at the graphic mod in bios.

Comment: Great, please mark your question as answered by clicking the green check mark next to the answer.